# 402 - Payment Required Response, Shopify API

Tags: shopify

I'll jump straight into it, we have 'n' clients, "A", "B", "C", "D" and "E"...

We have a working solution and all is working great! **Apart from client "E",** I'm faced with a `402 - Payment Required` response. To be honest the setup process is rather easy, **create private app** - leave default settings.

Now looking at shopify api documentation, it's states that the **store is frozen**, this is simply not true, as the store is  still trading.

Obviously tested in our `code base` and postman, it seems it's store specific. Having contacted the client, and access given to the backend, absolutely nothing is out of place, all settings are the same as the other clients.

Any Shopify API guru's out there to help me diagnose the error/problem? To reiterate, I'm faced with a **402 - payment required response**, any help is greatly appreciated.

**Postman:**
[image]

**Code Base:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this one was slightly embarrassing,

It turns out that the domain in question resolved to another, be sure to pump the domain in the url to see if it resolves/redirects to another.. after confirming that and used the domain it resolved to, it worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a carrier service or something that has a higher level of Shopify?